# MySQL update not updating all rows (using php)

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to update my values and something weird is happening, MySQL seems to be updating rows out of its own free will. Here is what I do

```
UPDATE accountsTable SET Status = 'TerminatedProfile' WHERE id IN (1,2,3)
```

And it updates either one or two rows not all 3, even if I run the code multiple times. And if I take this query and run it through phpmyadmin it works fine. Is there something wrong with php's mysql implementation or what?

I am using

```
mysql_connect("$host", "$user", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db")or die("cannot select DB"); 
mysql_query($query2);
```

Update:
I was running it on Joomla and perhaps it had something to do with session because one of the rows I was trying to update was on the admin user I was logged in with. Thanks for the responses specially MikeB.

Comment: You need to show your full code. There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with your query. Since you named your variable `$query2` I assume there's more going on then what you've shown.

Comment: You don't need any of the quotes in the parameters to `mysql_connect` or `mysql_select_db`.

Comment: @MikeB
THe query one simply gets the ids that I have written as (1,2,3) so there is really nothing more.
nick
As I said that query runs partially correct so I am sure there is nothing wrong with connection or anything.

Comment: @UsmanZaheer Create a php page with nothing but what you've shown us and you'll see that it works as expected. PHP/MySQL don't randomly decide to execute some parts of a query and not others.

Comment: @MikeB
Believe it or not that all there is to the page, I am trying to make a cron and the page just have 2 queries.
I myself am working with PHP and MySQL for long and never had such issue. This really is weird. It is same behavior on my local as well as live.

Comment: You still don't believe me? After executing your update do a select where id in (1,2,3) and dump all the row-data to verify your update query is being run. You have to do it in your script right after `mysql_query($query2)` so no other operations can interrupt the process.

Comment: I do that manually, and as I said every time the result is different. So I am sure the query IS run. I have also tried running update on each id separately but even that has the same result i.e. few of the rows being updated, not all.

Comment: I agree with @MikeB, we really need to see your full code.

Comment: @UsmanZaheer You're not understanding me. I'm suggesting that some other process somewhere is altering the rows. It might not even be the same script. Someone might be hitting a page on your server that alters the database rows. It doesn't really matter where it's coming from.. my point is that it's happening. "Manually verifying the query was executed" as you say is exactly the opposite of what you need to do to verify that your query above is working as intended.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to know what is going on without the full code or where $query2 has being applied.

But you can try to update these rows not using a list. Try:

```
UPDATE accountsTable SET Status = 'TerminatedProfile' WHERE id = 1 AND id = 2 AND id = 3
```

It's just to make sure the problem is or not where $query2 is.

You can also try to run this query right on mysql console, and see what happens. If works, probably the error is in how you're doing it.

Comment: I have even tried running all three (or so) rows as separate update queries and result remains the same. Some rows are updated and some are not.
And as I mentioned running it from phpmyadmin does work perfectly so I am doubting mysql class has something to do with it.